# cross resolution level design advice

Tags: 2d, tiles

I was looking for some beginner advice regarding level design across multiple resolutions.

I believe the answer is likely "it depends", but any input from anyone with real experience is very appreciated.

Basically, I am building a 2D Super Metroid type game. If rooms/levels are to be a tiled grid, what are some general best practices for designing rooms when taking into account different resolutions?

Since more or less tiles could fit vertically on a single screen depending on the resolution, is it better to design towards possibly having more of the room visible depending on the screen (with a bare minimum needed for gameplay), or should I fix the design at a certain tile height and scale the graphics?

Comment: Well this is of course only my opinion, but as a gamer I would appreciate it. You could design for a target screen resolution (measured in tiles!), and then have High and Low quality versions of the tiles themselves to better match the screen res (in pixels) to the target number of tiles.

Comment: I hate to say that out loud, but the only real answer is - **it depends**

Comment: Designing to an aspect ratio is probably all you can do, and add black bars accordingly (horizontal/vertical).